# Trap on setting property in constructor in ES6 Proxy

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I have code:

```js
class Foo {
  a: number;
  b?: number;

  constructor() {
    this.a = 1;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.b = 2;
    }, 1000);
  }

  update() {
    this.a = 10;
    this.b = 20;
  }
}

const instance = new Foo();

const proxy = new Proxy(instance, {
  set: function (target: Foo, prop: keyof Foo, value: any): boolean {
    console.log("update prop:", prop, value);

    target[prop] = value;
    return true;
  }
});

proxy.update();
```

Result:

```
update prop: a 10
update prop: b 20
```

I want to log also change maked in class constructor, so result should be:

```
update prop: a 1  // set in constructor
update prop: a 10
update prop: b 20
update prop: b 2  // set in constructor setTimeout
```

I know why this code don't work just like I want, but I have no idea how write this kind of code. Is this possible?

Comment: You want 2 thins: 1) dump all defined initial values - you can just do it aside before calling `new Proxy`, 2) monitor changes inside the proxied object - that's not possible, the object is not aware of the proxy. But anyway, setting timeouts in constructor is a bad idea. Maybe try to say what actual problem you are dealing with, this is obviously a contrived code example and we have no clue about your actual use case.

Comment: Agreed, this seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You could hack around it but I doubt it's really what you want.

Comment: @amik 1) Yep, you are right. But I can't handle this way an asynchronous changes. 2) I want to create, let say - controllers for React (like MobX). When happend any prop change in controller I need rerender component corelated with this controller. Often in contructor I want to make http request, and after get response set prop and after this I need run rerender.  [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontroller-poc-fozrc?file=/src/App.tsx), I bypass this problem by using extra method `onInit` instead of constructor but I think it's not cool.

Comment: Sounds like you actually *do* want an extra method. Make a private method that will initialise everything, then a factory method that creates an instance and calls the private method. This is how you handle stuff that shouldn't be in the constructor.

Comment: Well in that case you should not pass the "plain" controller anywhere, you have to pass the proxy everywhere. And you can pass the proxy to the controller itself, and write the controller so that it will use the proxy instead of "this" too. You won't be able to do any reasonable work or start async stuff in constructor then, but hey, as I previously said it is a terrible idea, `onInit` is definitely better.